# VLC lagging while running HD videos

Tags: ati, graphics, vlc, mp4

My vlc player keeps lagging while i play hd videos. To be more especific, it has been lagging in mp4 files with 720p and 1080p.

It keeps stopping like 10 seconds to 10 seconds. The stopping time is less than 1 second.

System : ubuntu 12.10, CPU intel i3, graphics are ati mobility radeon hd5145, 512mb dedicated. It's a laptop, asus K52JB

I hav open source ati driver installed.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I would be helpful if you could tell us more about the specifics of your hardware and OS.

Comment: ubuntu 12.10, CPU intel i3, graphics are ati mobility radeon hd5145, 512mb dedicated. It's a laptop, asus K52JB.

Comment: I would probably add that to the description. I can't actually help I just see that the more information you give us -- so long as its relevant -- the more likely it is that the community can help you.

Comment: Does that also happen with other player such as the default Movie Player (Totem) or only VLC?

Answer (score 6):

I had kind of the same issue, here's how I fixed it:

In VLC, I went to  / Tools / Preferences / Input & Codecs / Codecs ... and set "Skip H.264 in-loop deblocking filter" to "All".

And it worked just fine (it seems that I lost a bit in image quality, maybe you can try other settings for "Skip H.264 in-loop deblocking filter".

Remember to restart VLC.

Source: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=10510

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by disabling **video quality post-processing level**.
So to disable this option -
Open `vlc  Tools  Preferences  Input/Codecs`.
and now set **video quality post-processing level** to 0 (default is 6 & 0 means disabled).

*I was worked for me*.
*Thankyou!*

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`Tools / Preferences / Input & Codecs / Codecs / Hardware-accelerated Decoding`

And set it to `VA-API video decorder`.

And the quality and performance are night and day. Before it was stuttering and I could see pixels on 1080p videos. Now this is all gone.

VDPAU might be the default because I have the same problems when I switch to it. But this is a guess.