# Why does the VLC player has lag after pause?

Tags: graphics, video, vlc, cpu, mp4

why when I pause the vlc player and then start it after a few seconds, part of the movie doesn't play and jumps forward, while on Windows This problem did not occur.

My system specifications:
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
RAM: 6 GB
HDD: 1TB ==>0.5TB is used

Comment: Does this work? https://askubuntu.com/questions/221321/vlc-lagging-while-running-hd-videos/1341336#1341336

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi No, unfortunately it did not work

Answer (score 5):

Go to **Tools** -> **Preferences** -> in the bottom left corner below "**Show settings**" choose "**All**" -> **Input/Codecs** -> in the **Advanced** section the first setting is "**File caching**" -> Type a value below 300 ms like **200** or **100** (whatever works for ya)
Hope this helps

Comment: Any idea why this is a solution?  I only encountered this problem only after upgrading to 22.04 and don’t have it on a system with Manjaro+Cinnamon.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have VLC v3.x.
[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/VLC/comments/8oiwu9/303_stutterlag_when_resuming_after_pause_also/) (2yr old link) suggests downgrading to VLC v2.x can work.
Perhaps VLC v4, which is [provided as a snap](https://artifacts.videolan.org/vlc/nightly-snap/), can also help.

**Related**:

1. https://www.remosoftware.com/info/fix-vlc-player-lag-stutter-playing-hd-videos
2. https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=142568 (refers to a de-syncing audio/video after pause+resume)

Comment: I searched a lot but it seems that there is no version 2 vlc for Linux

Comment: @Truth - Possibly there is no precompiled package of ver 2.x for Ubuntu 20.04. You may have to compile from source.